# Android: TextView not updating

Tags: java, android, refresh, android-linearlayout, textview

I got one EditText and one TextView, and I want to update my TextView in each Iteration (ConsoleWindow is running in a loop; it gets called from a handler and thus is running on the UIthread).

The Problem is that my TextView only gets updated in the first round, and then it keeps the first entry for the rest of the runtime (although the `dataString` is a different one in each round):

```
private void ConsoleWindow(String dataString) {

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

            if (first2) { //first2 is true when application is launched
                // ONLY SET LAYOUT AND EDITTEXT IN FIRST RUN TO SAVE CAPACITY

                // LINEAR LAYOUT
                setContentView(layout);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // black

                // EDITTEXT
                EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                et.setHint("Enter Command");
                layout.addView(et);
                first2 = false;
            }


            // TEXTVIEW
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(dataString); // KEEPS THE SAME UNTIL THE 1ST ROUND
            layout.addView(tv);
}
```

I already tried tv.invalidate() and tv.postInvalidate(), but that didn't have an effect. Could someone help me please?

Comment: you dont ever get the textview to update, you create a new one

Comment: problem is that I cannot put the `new TextView` in the if-Statement, because otherwise `tv.setText(...)` cannot be executed (because its outside the if-statement)

Comment: you should be using `new TextView` anywhere since thats a `NEW` textview and not the one you are updating

Comment: you're right, "updating" is not the appropriate word. However, it shows me only the 1st TextView..

Comment: what is `dataStringTot`? Is it different from `dataString`?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter in this case. I'll change it in the code, its confusing a bit

Comment: When `first2` is `false`, you are just creating a new _LinearLayout_ `layout` and then directly you are adding _TextView_ `tv` to `layout`. That's why Textview is not visible.

Comment: After first2 is set to false, is this method being called again?

Comment: yes it is (its in a Loop). that's why i put an `if` to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put tv a global variable.

```
 private TextView tv;
```

After this, In your "onCreate()" method:

```
 tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

And then:

```
private void ConsoleWindow(String dataString) {

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

            if (first2) { //first2 is true when application is launched
                // ONLY SET LAYOUT AND EDITTEXT IN FIRST RUN TO SAVE CAPACITY

                // LINEAR LAYOUT
                setContentView(layout);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // black

                // EDITTEXT
                EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                et.setHint("Enter Command");
                layout.addView(et);
                first2 = false;
            }


            // TEXTVIEW
            tv.setText(dataString); // KEEPS THE SAME UNTIL THE 1ST ROUND
            layout.addView(tv);
}
```

Please verify too, if dataString has some text, with something like this

```
Log.d(TAG , "dataString: " + dataString + "with first time? " + first2.toString());
```

Try to pass to the setContentView(layout); outside the if statement.Because I can't understand well Why you need this.

```
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: yess finally worked! I can't believe I invested so much time in such a simple thing ^^ thank you!

Comment: Was the first solution? :)

Comment: nope, already had one; but that one didn't work with the declarations

Answer (score 1):

When `first2` is `false`, you are simply creating a new *LinearLayout* `layout` and then without inflating the `layout`, you are directly adding *TextView* `tv` to `layout`. That's why *Textvie*w is not visible.

```
private void ConsoleWindow(String dataString) {
    LinearLayout layout;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    if (first2) {
        layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(layout);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        // EDITTEXT
        et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        et.setHint("Enter Command");
        layout.addView(et);

        tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        layout.addView(tv);

        first2 = false;
    }
    if(tv != null) {
        tv.setText(dataString);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but still the same problem -.-